# Google Sheets - fill a cell with a hyperlink based on dropdown menu selection

Tags: google-sheets

so I have a spreadsheet i'm using to track clients workouts. To make life easier and faster when creating the workouts i created a series of dropdowns with exercises, body parts associated with that exercise etc... So when i select a body part from the dropdown menu for example "Quads" I will get a list of quad only exercises in the next dropdown menu. My question is, is there a way I can populate the "link" cells with hyperlinks associated with the exercise selection? So when i select an exercise the hyperlink for that exercise will appear in that cell?

I have a 2nd page that contains a list of all the exercise video hyperlinks but they are categorised by body parts. I have attached pictures for a better idea of what i'm working with. Hopefully this all makes sense :)

edit: also added spreadsheet

[image: tracker]

[image]

[Workout Tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LDWZCNPQsqunKxcdZ4vX6WXwjKd8nkWD4uaDgGTFr3s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.  Use **Insert > Note** to describe what you want in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks I have it added :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing a sample spreadsheet. Please clearly indicate where the _hand-entered_ expected results are. Use cell fill colors to flag the expected result cells.

Comment: I have added notes to demonstrate what I would like the end result to be. Please let me know if there is anything i need to clarify more on :)

Comment: You can improve your chances of getting an answer that works for you by showing your _hand-entered_ expected results. You note: _"Step 1 - Selecting a bodypart here narrows down the available exercises under the "Exercise" column"_ — this suggests that you need a **dependent drop-down list**. That is another question. Post in a new topic if you need help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in cell `K6` and copy the formula cell down:

```
=iferror( 
  vlookup( 
    C6, 
    filter( 
      'Exercise Database'!K$1:U, 
      'Exercise Database'!K$1:U$1 = B6 
    ), 
    1, 
    false 
  ) 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LDWZCNPQsqunKxcdZ4vX6WXwjKd8nkWD4uaDgGTFr3s/edit#gid=394330462).

The lookup would be simpler with `query()`, but it cannot reproduce clickable links.

Comment: Thank you so so much, that is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry again for any confusion caused by my lack of spreadsheet skills. You've made my job a whole lot easier :)